# Advantages of using Zend\Form?

Tags: forms, zend-framework2

Hello I am creating my website again but in Zend Framework,but I am confused,why there is a Zend\Form for creating forms?
I think the easiest way is create a view in HTML but maybe I am wrong..I would like to know why Zend provide us to create forms in that way.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It's easy to bind Objects to Forms and populate either the Object or the Form with each others Data. It is easy to provide Filters and/or Validators for the Form-Elements. You do not need to write more than `echo $this->formCollection($form)`, even if you have 120 Form-Elements. And changing the form doesn't really require you to change the view, too (depending on how you work). Form-Errors are easily attached to the specific elements, etc... etc...

This is object-oriented-programming (OOP). You don't **NEED** any of this, but boy it sure helps a lot to get stuff done.

Comment: Ok thanks,it's a complex way but you're true nad it is easy to reuse

Comment: I follow this answer, but as a new user of Zend (1) I also follow the OP's opinion. When you are familiar with HTML 5, it is so much faster and easier to set it up in HTML. But onces application(s) grow very large, Zend Forms can be very beneficial.

Comment: @nclsvh given how the frontend has evolved I'd argue that most have shifted towards frontend only forms and using only InputFilter on the backend. Frontend Frameworks work with JSON and personally I only use ZendForm backends during when I know the application is never going to be performance critical. Otherwise it's all frontend framework stuff and HTTP Communication ^^

Answer (score 0):

`Zend\Form` is not only for creating forms. It is also there for **validation**. When a user sumbits the form, and you get the data, `Zend\Form` can validate the data for you. For example, it can check if a password is at least 8 characters. Or if an email address is actually a valid email address.

Comment: `Zend\Validate` is for Validation ;) `Zend\Form` however provides the infrastructure to combine the two of them.